# How to optimize constant querying for a sum of many rows?

Tags: performance, query-cache

I'm making an app that is supposed to view election results (yep, homework assignment). For each of the 24681 wards and each of the 12 candidates the number of votes the said candidate has received in the said ward is to be stored.

The most common operation, of course, would be viewing voting results aggregated over all election wards. Also there must be separate tables for each province, electoral district and municipality. Viewing aggregate voting results for each of these areas must also be possible.

Aggregating election results over the whole country takes up time measured in seconds. I consider this inappropriate even despite it's only a homework assignment. If this app was to be exposed to general public it would be unusable. I think it is broken to require aggregating results over 24681 wards each time a user loads the main page!

One way to counter that would be to store aggregated results for each territory (ward, municipality, province, district, whole country) in the database. This, however, would break normal forms pretty badly and I'm not sure if that's acceptable.

I'm thinking about database views. I'm imagining that the database would cache the results of views just as if I would break normal forms by adding relevant tables and columns myself and automatically recreate this cache for each larger area each time election results for the smaller area are modified (yes, editing the number of votes for each candidate in each ward is required). Can I make views work that way?

How else can I combat this issue?

Comment: You should probably tag the DBMS you are using, how things are cached etc depends on what DBMS you are using.

Comment: @Lennart Tbh, I'd just wanna know what DBMSs can do what...

Comment: @Lennart I still can change the DBMS. Provided it's free, don't wanna pay money to do my homework. So MySQL or Postres OK, but Oracle not really.

Comment: If concerned about having points taken off for thinking beyond the assignment, then first make sure you've fulfilled the assignment, and take a backup of everything at that point (if possible); then, establish the additional requirements you're adding (presumably, performance isn't a requirement for the assignment), and the changes you'd make to meet those. With that sort of clear divider, you shouldn't have points taken off for thinking beyond the literal assignment.

Comment: There are free versions of commercial DBMS:s like Oracle as well, but ok I see your point. I would start by getting it logically correct first, why do you need a separate table for each province for example?

Comment: @Lennart Each province is divided into districts. The webpage that shows informations for a particular province must contain links to each of that province's districts. Also provinces must be editable (addable, removable) through a Web interface. So there's a one-to-many relationship between a municipality and its wards, between a district and its municipalities and between a province and its districts.

Answer (score 3):

The concept you want is called a "materialized view". Normally, a view is fundamentally just a query prepared in advance, that you can reference like a table for convenience. A materialized view is at least partially stored in the database.

In SQL Server, this is done by creating an *indexed view*. This acts as an index tied to the table(s) in the view, and is updated when the underlying rows are updated, just like any other index. Note that the SQL Server Developer's Edition is free, and has very few limits on it.

Near as I can tell, neither MYSQL nor PostGreSQL provide this feature in this form.

With such a materialized view, you still have a potential for a performance issue. Since the index is updated every time the underlying rows are updated, if you're trying to tally up votes in real time, you may find that the view is constantly being modified. Between frequent `SELECT`s against the view, and constant `INSERT`s and/or `UPDATE`S on the underlying tables, you may face blocking issues, a major problem if it prevents you from showing results, and an even worse problem if it prevents votes from being entered in the first place!

You may want to think about another option. Consider if you need a real-time tally, or if one that's been updated recently (say, within the last 5 minutes) would be sufficient. From what I've seen in election results in the US, that's the path they seem to take.

Answer (score 1):

It is heartening to see that you are concerned about normalization. That will serve you well through your career. Stick with it.

All real-world implementations have their limitations, however. Even 128 cores and 1TB RAM will struggle with petabytes of data. The trick, then, is to do the best with what you've got.

Start with the queries. Are they returning the minimum amount of data? Doing more work than required is slower.

Have you got indexes in place? Do they match the query predicates? Is the optimizer using them? Some DBMS allow WHERE clauses on index definitions. This limits both the work on write and on read. Is clustering defined appropriately?

There are different technologies for storing data. Traditional engines are optimised for disk. Recently memory-optimized engines have become common. Without the IO and with different concurrency techniques they run much faster. Traditionally data has been stored row-wise. Now column stores are available. They are especially good for aggregate queries.

There are engines that specialise in the kind of rollup queries you need called [OLAP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing). Some are updated in batch, some synchronously. Most need a separate query language. Not sure if this is overkill for homework.

None of the above will break normalization.

By denormalizing data you hold a value more than once. The problem is to keep the copies synchronised. This task can be delegated to the application, which is OK for small, short projects. Better to have it in the DBMS, though. Triggers are one approach. A write to a low-level value will be duplicated to the next higher level and so on. Be aware that the top-level Tables get very "hot" and may become a bottlneck.

If a small amount of variance is acceptable caching values in the client helps performance greatly. Perhaps only do the nation-wide query every 30s, say, and perform it asynchronously so the app's latency is not affected.

Generaty speaking, view results are not cached separately. When a query referencing a view is parsed and compiled the view's definition is substituted into the query's SQL and *that* is executed. Materialized views, as mentioned in another answer, do store the results separately.